# How to customize order succes page url and add some order details

Tags: magento2, orders, onestepcheckout, order-success-page

I want my order success page URL(**checkout/onepage/success/**) to be changed to **order/?ORDERID**

And I need to display some order details in that success page. That should be shown even after the reload.

I have tried to get some details by calling a phtml in **checkout_onepage_success.xml**

But this is not exactly I want.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that.

First, You have to build a module which frontName is  `order`.Check [What is a frontName?](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html)

Second is that  redirect to `checkout/onepage/success/` to `order/?ORDERID`

### Create URL:

First, As you want to start url with `order`, So the `routes.xml` code at **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend**.Will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
    <!-- frontname is Order as you want to uRL is Frontend -->
        <route id="order" frontName="order">
            <module name="{Vendorname}_{Modulename}" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and  You have to  create Action file `Index.php` at **app/code/{Vendorname}/{Modulename}/Controller/Index**

And Code Should be like:

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Modulename}\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            ['order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()]]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

### Redirect `checkout/onepage/success/` to order/?ORDERID

On this case,  you have to  create a plugin over `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success` ,  create around plugin on  `execute()`